# Clean installation missing its /wp-content folder

Tags: directory, ftp

I installed WordPress 4.1 on my server. All the files are installed, and I can login correctly without errors. But if I login through FTP I can't find the `wp-content` folder.
If I do the above on my server panel through the file browser I can see the `wp-content` folder correctly.

For some reason it is hidden when browsing through the FTP client. I tried FileZilla but also other FTP clients. All of them do not show the `wp-content` folder.

I tried to change the folder permissions, but no effect.

Anyone knows how to fix this, or what the cause of it might be?

Answer (score 2):

I kept on searching, and finally found something that fixed this issue.
For those who are using CentOs 7 in combination with Plesk 12:

**The issue is with SELinux.**

> When it’s used in Enforcing mode (which is the default), `wp-content`
>   does not show itself via FTP. Switching it to Permissive mode or
>   disabling SELinux altogether solves the problem.
>
> The entire issue will be fixed in the next release of Plesk, and it’s
>   already working in the latest update to the Plesk Preview 12.1.13.
>   CentOS 5 and 6 are not affected.

To disable SELinux on CentOS 7 we can use this: `setenforce 0`

Or, to switch to permissive mode, use this: `setenforce permissive`

Now we’ll need to restart the xinetd service as well as Plesk for the changes to take effect:

```
systemctl restart xinetd.service
service psa stopall
service psa restart
```

If the server is restarted the above settings will be lost.
To permanently use the above settings you should edit the selinux config file:

```
vi /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```